# Accessing JavaScript Function in an HTML Page From an external JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-analytics

I have a JavaScript Function in an HTML Page's . It will return a value. The returning value must be caught from another JavaScript Function. This 2nd JavaScript Function is in an external JavaScript File. This external JS File is linked to the HTML file.

So how am I suppose to do this.

Could someone help me on this matter?

Thanks and regards,
Chiranthaka

**Update**

*HTML File.(Dashboard.html)*

```
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function setJsonSer() {
                    formData = {
                    'Email': 'clientlink@russell.com',
                    'Password': 'russell1234',
                    'URL': getVaria()
                };
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "/APIWebService.asmx/AnalyticsDataShowWithPost",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    complete: function(data) {
                        alert("Set JSON In  "+JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                 });

            $.ajax({
                url: "/APIWebService.asmx/AnalyticsDataShowWithPost",
                type: 'GET',
                data: formData,
                complete: function(data) {
                    alert("Get JSON Out  "+JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });
      }

   </script>
</head>
```

*External JavaScript File - Script.js*

```
function retStartDate(){

 var strStartDate = document.getElementById("from_date").value;

 alert("Start date " + strStartDate);

 return strStartDate;

}

function retEndDate(){

 var strEndDate = document.getElementById("to_date").value;

 alert("End date " + strEndDate);

 return strEndDate;

}

function getVaria(){

 alert(retEndDate());

 var strWsUrl =
   'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A76546294&dimensions='+
   'ga%3Asource&metrics=ga%3Ausers&sort=-ga%3Ausers&start-  
   date='+retStartDate()+'&       
   end-date='+retEndDate()+'&max-results=10';

 alert("Query String "+strWsUrl);

 return strWsUrl;

 }
```

**--End of update ----**

Comment: This question does not have enough detail. You need to show how the external JS file is declaring its function. There are some ways of declaring functions that prevent it from appearing in the global scope. Without seeing code, we have no way of knowing if this is the case

Comment: There is quite a lot of code there. What function are you having trouble calling?

Comment: function `setJasonSer(){   }`

Comment: ?? but you're not calling `setJasonSer` from your external file

Comment: I want to call that setJsonSer() from the external JavaScript File.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML page you need to define a function which is globally accessible.

For example the following function `foo` will be accessible from your external file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo (){
        // do something
    }
</script>
```

This simple trick trick should do the trick.

Comment: When your answer considered setJasonSer() function in the HTML page within the <head></head> can be caught from the external JavaScript File?

Comment: Yes you can access `setJasonSer()` within head tag from external file.

Comment: Then how can I do that pal?

Comment: I have uploaded an example with explanation:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rxo833dzch9gnqc/ExternalAccess.zip?dl=0

Please have a look.